# When in full screened windows in Windows 10, the very bottom of window is covered by toolbar

Tags: windows, browser, resizing, desktop-toolbar

Alright, so this is a minor, but very annoying issue with Windows 10. When I either snap an application window to the side or put the screen to full screen, the application by default is taking up the full part of the monitor, including the part under the toolbar, forcing me to resize the window if I want to access anything under the tool bar itself. How do I set the default to that when in the maximize mode, it stops at the toolbar instead of the entire screen size?

Here is a screen shot of sort of whats happening whenever I try to resize:

[image]

Comment: Upload your image to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get a link you can share. [Edit] your question to include this link and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image for you.

Comment: Do you use an external monitor aswell?

Answer (score 0):

I've seent this problem before and it should be solved in one of the following ways:

Alternative 1: Set taskbar to autohide by right-clicking the taskbar, choose properties and then check the "Auto-hide the taskbar" box followed > OK, then perform a reboot.

When the OS is rebooted, uncheck the box then reboot.

Alternative 2:
Set taskbar to autohide by right-clicking the taskbar, choose properties and then check the "Auto-hide the taskbar" box followed > OK, then perform a reboot.
Then right-click the toolbar, choose Task Maanager > go to details > Right-click Explorer.exe > Click "End Task".

Then click File in Task Manager > Run  > type: Explorer.exe

Now uncheck the box then repeat the process.